# how to forbid multiple fopen() of same file

Tags: c, bash, sh, fopen, environment

I have a C program which opens same file more than one time like this:

```
FILE *fp1 = fopen("/path/to/file","r");
// Without/beore closing fp1
FILE *fp2 = fopen("/path/to/file","r");
```

I want to make the second fopen() fail, while I run the program .

Assume I am running my the C programme/executable from  `GNU Bash shell (/bin/bash)`, or `Bourne shell (/bin/sh)`.

Is there any setting/configuration I can do in my shell environment such that it will not allow same program to open same file more than one times simultaneously. So that the second fopen() will fail (i.e. will return NULL) ?

Comment: The shell that runs a program has no effect on how the program runs.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do what you want. You can use file locks to prevent different processes from opening a file, but I don't think they affect opening within the same process.

Comment: The program should just keep track of which files it has opened, and notice when it tries to open the same file twice. You can write `my_fopen()` and `my_fclose` functions that keep a list of opened files in an array and check against it.

Comment: @Barmar I cant change the program. I am only ttrying  to make that program fail.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then.

Comment: This sounds like it might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/225338).  Can you explain why you want to achieve this unusual goal?

Comment: One (crude) way to do this is to limit the number of files opened by this process by setting "ulimit -n 4" in the shell that launches it. Then it can open STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR as usual and then this specific file once.

Comment: @Ramana ^ This did the trick..

Answer (score 0):

You could use open instead of fopen and pass in the O_EXCL flag.